# ReactDOM expecting String but returning an Object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, graphql-js

I am running an application using React and Graphql. I am getting the following error:

```
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.
```

When running the following code:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { ApolloProvider } from 'react-apollo';
import { ApolloClient } from 'apollo-client';
import { HttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http';
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory';

import Routes from './routes';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: new HttpLink({ uri: 'http://localhost:8080' }),
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
});

const App = (
  <ApolloProvider client={client}>
     <Routes />
  </ApolloProvider>
);

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

I am getting the error on the line that includes `ReactDOM.render();` because it is returning an object instead of a string. I am not understanding why it is requesting a String and returning an object.

In the routes directory I have:

index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

import Home from './Home';

export default () => (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
    </Switch>
  </BrowserRouter>
);
```

And Home.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { graphql } from 'react-apollo';
import gql from 'graphql-tag';

const Home = ({ data: { loading, allUsers } }) =>
  (loading ? null : allUsers.map(u => <h1 key={u.id}>{u.email}</h1>));

const allUsersQuery = gql`
  {
    allUsers {
      id
      email
    }
  }
`;

export default graphql(allUsersQuery)(Home);
```

Comment: What is `<Routes />`

Comment: @Tony just updated it with more code in the Routes directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the exact reason why, perhaps someone can chime in, but you can't have your component like this:

```
const App = (
  <ApolloProvider client={client}>
     <Routes />
  </ApolloProvider>
);
```

If you use `ReactDOM.render(<App />, ...)`

If you change it to a functional component as follows, it should work:

```
const App = () => (
  <ApolloProvider client={client}>
     <Routes />
  </ApolloProvider>
);
```

However, you could also just do `ReactDOM.render(App, ...)` without changing it to a function.

Comment: You are correct, that fixed it. Thank you! If anyone does know the reason and could explain, that'd be great.

Comment: I updated my answer with some extra info @user081608